# How i can replace the images of a Treeview used to expand and collapse a node?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using the **TCustomTreeView.OnCustomDrawItem** event to change the color of the nodes of a TTreeview, but now i need to replace the image used to expand and collapse the nodes, but i'm stuck with this. How i can replace the images of a Treeview used to expand a collapse a node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard `TTreeView` component does not allow you to replace the expand/collapse images, either directly or via owner-drawing.  You will have to find a third-party TreeView component that supports it.

Comment: See [VirtualTreeView](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/virtualtreeview/info) for such a component.